# How to prove that: $\forall a \in \Bbb R,$ $\|f+a\|_p\ge \frac12\|f\|_p$ when $\int_\Omega f(x)dx= 0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, inequality, lp-spaces

Let $\Omega $ be any subset of $\Bbb R^d$ and $f\in L^p(\Omega)$ such that

$$\int_\Omega f(x)dx= 0$$

> Then, shows that for each real number  $a\in \Bbb R,$ we have $$\|f+a\|_{L^p(\Omega )}\ge \frac12\|f\|_{L^p(\Omega )}$$

This looks obvious but but spent already a lot of time on it.

I noticed that it sufficed to prove the inequality  for $a>0 $. the case  $p=2$ is been trivial using quadratic.
Any Hint or idea?

Answer (score 6):

You need to assume $a\in L^p(\Omega)$, otherwise $f+a\notin L^p(\Omega)$. By Minkowski's inequality, $$\|f\|_p\leq \|f+a\|_p+\|a\|_p $$
Now it remains to prove that $\|a\|_p\leq \|f+a\|_p $, using the fact that $\int_{\Omega}f=0$.

Hint: Apply Jensen's inequality to $f+a$ and $x\mapsto |x|^p$.

Edit: I suppose you can also obtain it by applying Holder's inequality to $(f+a)\cdot 1$.

Edit2: I will write a more detailed proof since it is not clear enough apparently. OP is considering a function $f+a$, where $f\in L^p(\Omega)$ and $a\in \mathbb{R}$. The function $f+a$ is the map
$$ (f+a)(x)= f(x)+a,\qquad \forall x\in \Omega$$
This is the exactly the same as considering the sum of *functions* $f+a$, where $a$ is the *constant function* $a(x)=a$ for all $x\in \Omega$. Notice that
$$(f+a)(x)=f(x)+a(x)=f(x)+a,\qquad \forall x\in \Omega $$
which is exactly the equality written above. As a *function*, $a\in L^p(\Omega)$, i.e. $\|a\|_p<\infty$, because $L^p(\Omega)$ is a vector space and $f+a,f\in L^p(\Omega)$. Hence by Minkowski's inequality, 
$$\|f\|_p\leq \|f+a\|_p+\|a\|_p $$
Assume $p\neq \infty$:
since $a\in L^p$, we have $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$. By applying Holder's inequality to $1\cdot(f+a)$ we obtain
$$\mu(\Omega)|a|=\left|\int_{\Omega} a\right| =\left|\int_{\Omega}(f+a)\right|\leq \int_{\Omega}|f+a|\leq \|1\|_{p'}\|f+a\|_p=\mu(\Omega)^{1-1/p}\|f+a\|_p$$
Thus
$$\|a\|_p=\left(\int_{\Omega}|a|^p\right)^{1/p}=\mu(\Omega)^{1/p}|a|\leq\|f+a\|_p $$
If $p=\infty$ the inequality $\|a\|_{\infty}\leq \|f+a\|_{\infty}$ is trivial because since $\int_{\Omega}f=0$, then $f$ takes both non-negative and non-positive values on nonzero measure subsets of $\Omega$.

Putting this together with Minkowski's inequality we get $\|f\|_p\leq 2\|f+a\|_p$.

Comment: $a$ is just a vector. what do you mean by $||a||_p$?

Comment: Oh well, it should be $a\in \mathbb{R}$ otherwise $f+a$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: In that case isn't $a$ just a number? why does it have to represent a function?

Comment: You treat it as a function over $\Omega$ with constant value $a$. Formally, for the expression $f+a$ to make sense, both $f$ and $a$ need to be functions.

Comment: in that case you don't need to say $a\in L^p$ instead that $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$ where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure. But this is quite a restriction.

Comment: Well, $a\in L^p \iff \mu(\Omega)<\infty$ (unless $p=\infty$, which is not the main point I guess). The thing is OP assumed $f+a\in L^p$, and since $L^p$ is a vector space, $f,f+a\in L^p$ implies $(f+a)-f=a\in L^p$. In other words, their inequality doesn't make sense if $\mu(\Omega)=\infty$.

Comment: thanks for your answer but $a\Bbb R$ is a real number so this answer is troubling me.

Comment: @LorenzoQ. if $f+a\not\in L^p$ then the inequality is blatantly true since $$\|f+a\|_p=\infty$$

Comment: What do you mean with $f+a$ if not the function $x\mapsto f(x)+a$? That is the same as considering the function $f+a:x\mapsto f(x)+a(x)$, where $a$ is the constant function $x\mapsto a(x)=a$.

Comment: @Arian $\Omega$ do not necessarily has finite measure.

Comment: @LorenzoQ. sorry my bad that was a misprinting in my question I fixed it. a is  a real number.

Comment: @GuyFsone  If you define $\|\cdot\|_p$ as a norm on the vector space $L^p(\Omega)$, then it is not defined for $f+a\notin L^p(\Omega)$. Sure, you may also write $\|f+a\|_p=\infty$, but as you said, in this case the inequality is trivial and not very interesting.

Comment: +1: upvoted for nice application of Jensen's inequality.

Comment: @GNUSupporter this answer is not appropriate. since a is a constante and may not have finite norm

Comment: What? If it has no finite norm then $\|f+a\|_p=\infty$ and I quote your words 'it is blatantly true'.

Comment: @LorenzoQ. also not that $\Omega$ is not bounded. so you should think of your inequalities involving. $\|a\|_p$ it is dangereous

Comment: As I already said, $a\in L^p(\Omega)$ is equivalent to $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$. I never used that $\Omega$ is bounded but only that $a\in L^p(\Omega)\iff \mu(\Omega)<\infty$, which follows directly from $\|f+a\|<\infty$.

Comment: This is wrong $a\in L^p(\Omega)$

Comment: since there is not further assumption saying the $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm done, I've explained everything clearly enough, I'm just ending up repeating myself over and over again.

Comment: Where did you pick this  ? $a\in L^p(\Omega)\iff \mu(\Omega)<\infty$ ?

Comment: this makes no sense $\|a\|_p=\left(\int_{\Omega}|a|^p\right)^{1/p}=\mu(\Omega)^{1/p}|a|\leq\|f+a\|_p $ if $\mu(\Omega)=\infty$